# How to optimize all these objects in 1 Prop to Game?

Tags: mesh, objects, particles, unity, optimization

I'm looking for a way to optimize all the popcorn particles to make a single object optimized to serve as a prop for games. What better method?

[image]

[image]

Putting together all the popcorns the numbers are absurd for a single Prop:

499 Objects

61,546 Vertices

93,706 Faces

120,836 Tris

**NOTE:** All popcorn are already optimized to the maximum that I believe do not make them completely ugly or strange.

Comment: retopology and normal mapping is your friend here. create a low poly mesh with just the surface of the popcorn layer (with however much detail you polycount allows for) and bake a normal map from your existing mesh.